# Mouse moving automatically to newly opened window

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and at some point today a new feature got enabled whereby on some occasions my mouse moves to newly opened windows by itself. I am now trying to disable that feature. I've searched in the `mouse` and `assistive technologies` system settings but couldn't find anything. I've also googled for it but all I get is noise.

Can someone assist please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the very same issue with my Ubuntu 10.04 system. I am not exactly sure, but I think it is a bug in one of the Compiz plugins.

I was able to solve this by disabling the Accessibility plugin "Enhanced Zoom Desktop" in the CompizConfig Settings Manager (System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager). If it is not installed on your system, then you have to manually install the compizconfig-settings-manager package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to toggle the [Focus and Raise Behaviour](http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.com/2010/08/opening-new-window-in-ubuntu-1004-does.html).

It can be found at **System → Preferences → CompizConfig Settings Manager → General Options → Focus & Raise Behaviour**.